# Visual Studio folding solution items recursively

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2019, csproj, solution

I am trying to fold all XAML dependents files.

```
<None Include=".\**\*.xaml.js">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  <DependentUpon>.\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)</DependentUpon>
</None>
<None Include=".\**\*.xaml.d.ts">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  <DependentUpon>.\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)</DependentUpon>
</None>
```

**I was able to fold JSs but TS definitions fail**

[image: Look at the last item with arrow]

I tried to create a "temp" items collection and tried to iterate and parse paths ... no success VS didn't load the project anymore

```
<ToFold Include=".\**\*.xaml" />
<None Include="@(ToFold->%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName).js')" DependentUpon="@(ToFold)">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```

I tried the same way in "another way" ... same way :(

```
<ToFold Include=".\**\*.xaml" />
<None Include="@(ToFold->%(ToFold).js')" DependentUpon="@(ToFold)">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```

### Question

- Is it possible to parse path in another way than `x->%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName` ?
- Is it possible to fold items like `*.dash.ext` ? How ?
- Or someone could help me achieving this ?!

**NOTE**

`xaml.ts` are auto generated and somehow auto folded

Comment: Did your first xaml code work? In my side, I cannot work it. As for me, I used these code to fold the files: `<None Include="..\**\*.xaml.d.ts"><CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory><DependentUpon>..\**\KYCHome.xaml.d.ts</DependentUpon></None>`

Comment: If `<DependentUpon>..\**\KYCHome.xaml.d.ts</DependentUpon>` works it wont address my issue ; it would only apply on `KYCHome.xaml.d.ts` which is not what I'm looking for

Comment: What kind of project is it? an SDK-based project, e.g. net core 3.1 or classic non-sdk .net framework? b/c for one you'd be better off with `Update=".."` and for the other one with `Include=".."`. Plus there are new automatic dependent-upon features in SDK based projects you could use

Comment: @FabriceT, any update about this issue?

Comment: Sorry for delay ... Martin -- it is a net core3.1 (ASP), Perny -- I don't know what happened but now JS doesn't works also, I'm updating my question

Comment: Hey Perry, it worked ! but I had found another solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that:

For `KYCHome.xaml.d.ts` file, the value of `%(FileName)` is `KYCHome.xaml.d` rather than `KYCHome.xaml`. So when you use it, it will not find the `KYCHome.xaml` file.

So the method I can think of is to intercept the `FileName`, remove the `.d`, and then the changed value is what we need.

**Solution**

This is what I used:

```
<ItemGroup>
        <None Include=".\**\*.xaml.js">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            <DependentUpon>%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)</DependentUpon>
        </None>
        <None Include=".\**\*.xaml.d.ts">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>   
            <File>$([System.String]::Copy('%(Filename)').Replace('.d', ''))</File>
            <DependentUpon>%(RecursiveDir)%(File)</DependentUpon>
        </None>
        
</ItemGroup>
```

**Note**: you should remove the `.\` under `DependentUpon` node. **Otherwise**, sometimes, the `DependentUpon` will not work when you restart your project or unload the project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm first French and I think it was a barrier for me to achieve what I wanted to do. I was saying **folding items** but if instead I had said **nesting items** I would quickly get my answer from google.

Visual Studio has a nesting items feature

[image: Nesting items button]

I got the answer from here [Path segment pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/file-nesting-solution-explorer?view=vs-2019#the-pathsegment-provider) and here is the node I added in the `.filenesting.json` solution  file

```
"dependentFileProviders": {
  "add": {
    "addedExtension": {},
    "pathSegment": {},
    "fileSuffixToExtension": {
      "add": {
        ".xaml.d.ts": [".xaml"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: The files nested]